# How to draw on canvas(with mouse/touch), save the drawn object, store it, load and manipulate?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I would like to know if there is any framework that allow me to store canvas drawn objects, load and manipulate, or if there isnt, how to do such process (if possible).

My objective is to procceed this steps:

1. Draw on canvas with mouse/touch on mobile devices
2. Store the drawn object in a way I can manipulate later (not as image file)
   (with store I mean to save it remotely on any kind of source)
3. Load the drawn object to canvas, and be able to manipulate him (bending a line p.ex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `base64` + `localStorage`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];  
var pngBase64 = canvas.toDataURL();
localStorage.setItem('myCanvasData', pngBase64);
```

Comment: imagine i have various items on canvas, how can i just capture the drawn one?, is it possible trough a draw area, or p.ex trough a capture time ? "-click start capture -> draw -> click stop capture -> store"

Comment: You can capture only whole canvas. If you need `draw layers` best practice is using several canvas.